# ReferenceError: Metadata for "GoogleMaps.GMSGeometryDistance" found but symbol not available at runtime

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, nativescript

I'm using the nativescript-google-maps-utils plugin in a NativeScript JavaScript project to access GoogleMapsUtils functions (GMSGeometryDistance, GMSGeometryInterpolate, and GMSGeometryHeading) so that I can traverse a polyline.  The Android equivalents work fine on Android devices, and the iOS functions listed work on an iOS simulator, but on an iOS device I get the exception,

`ReferenceError: Metadata for "GoogleMaps.GMSGeometryDistance" found but symbol not available at runtime.`

I've been chasing this for the better part of a day and still don't have any leads; I'd welcome any insight.

[edit]

It's worth mentioning I've done the usual removal of the platforms, hooks, and node-modules folders and rebuilt, with no change in the error.

Here's the first line of code that triggers the error:

`let lineDistance = GMSGeometryDistance(latlngs[i], latlngs[i + 1]);`

[edit 2]

Still chasing this...  I gather from [this issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4157) that I need to create a file with a list of exported symbols, and [this issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime/issues/1061) kind of suggests how that could be done, but I'm not understanding how that applies to this situation.

That is, the question at hand now is how can I determine the symbols from the iOS GoogleMapsUtils static library?  This is becoming more of an iOS and Xcode question that NativeScript or JavaScript.

[edit 3]

Sigh...  I *did* get this working using the answer I provided below, but now that same approach is no longer working. No idea why :-(

[edit 4]

I re-reviewed the links I referenced above and included the STRIPFLAGS option and now the code works properly.  I revised the answer to include this, and to edit `build.xcconfig` rather than the project file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After another day's investigation I was able to get this working.  Here's what it took.

1. Navigate to `/platforms/iOS/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/`
2. Run `nm --defined-only GoogleMaps | grep " T " | cut -f 3 -d' ' | egrep -v '^$|GoogleMaps'`
3. Notice the names of the symbols.  In my case each one I needed was the function name prefixed with an underscore
4. Create the file `exportedSymbols.txt` in `/app/App_Resources/iOS`
5. Add the symbols to the file.  In my case the contents is:

   `_GMSGeometryDistance`
   `_GMSGeometryHeading`
   `_GMSGeometryInterpolate`
6. Edit the file `app/App_Resources/iOS/build.xcconfig` and add these two lines

   `STRIPFLAGS=$(inherited) -s  {PROJECT_DIR}/../../app/App_Resources/iOS/exportedSymbols.txt`
   `EXPORTED_SYMBOLS_FILE = ${PROJECT_DIR}/../../app/App_Resources/iOS/exportedSymbols.txt`

So far this is working in my tests on both iOS simulators and devices.

Comment: Thanks for your description, I recently encountered the same problem and I was able to test on simulator and device following your steps. However, I am not able to archive the release build in Xcode, I am always getting the following error:

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip: can't open: {PROJECT_DIR}/../../app/App_Resources/iOS/exportedSymbols.txt (No such file or directory)
Command Strip failed with a nonzero exit code

Did you have a similar problem or is this working for you as expected?

Comment: It's working for me.  Your error message suggests that {PROJECT_DIR} is not being resolved.  See what happens if you use a hard-coded path, at least to check that assumption.

Comment: Thank you this helped me! I was using a cocoapod but non of the top level functions were founding in the ios runtime until I listed them in the exported symbols file.